# Convert custom log file into TSV (shell script)

Tags: shell, awk

I'm working on a script (shell) witch converts a custom log file (500M~2G) with 7 fields into tab-delimited file, then import it to MONGODB while the time of conversion is important. Log format (input file format):

```
date   time       src_ip       dst_ip     "user" "useragent" http_url
```

I tried below AWK command but it take too long for a 1GB log file(event with parallel)! Is there another way to do this faster?

```
cat file.log | awk -vFPAT='([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -vOFS='[ \t]+' '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7}' > res.tsv
```

Update: Input Log Sample (delimiter: multiple spaces /\s+/):

```
2017-03-01  12:23:02     192.168.1.5   204.79.197.200   "admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" http://www.bing.com/  
2017-03-01  12:23:05     192.168.1.12   13.82.28.61   "user1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" http://www.msn.com/  
2017-03-01  12:23:05     192.168.1.12   204.79.197.200   "user1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" http://www.bing.com/  
2017-03-01  12:23:06     192.168.1.24   172.227.89.22   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" http://www.fifa.com/
```

Output (tab delimited):

```
2017-03-01\t12:23:02\t192.168.1.5\t204.79.197.200\t"admin"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.bing.com/  
2017-03-01\t12:23:05\t192.168.1.12\t13.82.28.61\t"user1"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.msn.com/  
2017-03-01\t12:23:05\t192.168.1.12\t204.79.197.200\t"user1"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.bing.com/  
2017-03-01\t12:23:06\t192.168.1.24\t172.227.89.22\t"-"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"\thttp://www.fifa.com/
```

Only UserAgent field contains spaces.

Comment: Can you please give a specific example of the input format and what the corresponding output would look like?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Final purpose is to import this logs in mongodb so i'm guessing i need to convert them to csv or tsv for import.

Comment: @EdMorton These are inputs ... I want to convert them into tab delimited file so i can import in database.

Comment: is the white space in your sample input a `tab` char, or multiple spaces? And again, please update your Q to show required **output** from your sample input. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton I can't cause there is one space between fields too! [the number of spaces differs]

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sorry i'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v s='\\t' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {gsub(/ +/,s,$1); $3=s; gsub(/ +/,s,$5)}1' file
2017-03-01\t12:23:02\t192.168.1.5\t204.79.197.200\t"admin"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.bing.com/
2017-03-01\t12:23:05\t192.168.1.12\t13.82.28.61\t"user1"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.msn.com/
2017-03-01\t12:23:05\t192.168.1.12\t204.79.197.200\t"user1"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"\thttp://www.bing.com/
2017-03-01\t12:23:06\t192.168.1.24\t172.227.89.22\t"-"\t"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"\thttp://www.fifa.com/
```

Just change `s='\\t'` to `s='\t'` when you're happy with how it looks.

Comment: It worked for me ... i mixed it up with parallel command and results where good. So Is this the fastest way to do the converting?